# HackerRank Plus Minus ~ no response on stdout ~

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain why hackerrank does not accept this code for python?

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    positive = "{0:.6f}".format(sum(1 for i in arr if i > 0) / len(arr))
    negative = "{0:.6f}".format(sum(1 for i in arr if i < 0) / len(arr))
    zero = "{0:.6f}".format(sum(1 for i in arr if i == 0) / len(arr))
    return "\n".join([positive, negative, zero])
```

It gives me this error: `~ no response on stdout ~`

Comment: It usually happens when the program is slow. In this case, `arr` will be a huge list. So, your program might be taking long time.

Comment: if you count positives and negatives then you don't have to count zeros  because `zeros = len(arr) - positives - negatives`

Comment: i turned it into a single basic for-loop yet it gives me the same error

Comment: use module `time` to see how fast is your code for some big data. And you could add link to this challenge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice that on HackerRank your function is called without doing anything with the return value. The template code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

Moreover, the description says:

> **Print** the decimal value of each fraction on a new line.

So you should *print* the result. And since your code doesn't print anything, the error message is what could be expected.

Instead of `return`, do:

```
print("\n".join([positive, negative, zero]))
```

Comment: Ahh yes! That's what I missed. Thank you!